# PHP using MySQL 'mysqli_multi_query' more than one time?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to execute following PHP code, however just first statement gets executed successfully and rest following don't.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($link, 'database_name');


$update = " UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 1000 WHERE `id` = 1;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 2000 WHERE `id` = 2;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 3000 WHERE `id` = 3;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 4000 WHERE `id` = 4;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 5000 WHERE `id` = 5;";

mysqli_multi_query($link, $update);

$update2 = "UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 6000 WHERE `id` = 6;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 7000 WHERE `id` = 7;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 8000 WHERE `id` = 8;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 9000 WHERE `id` = 9;
            UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 10000 WHERE `id` = 10;";

mysqli_multi_query($link, $update2);

?>
```

**mysqli_multi_query($link, $update);** - *Executed Successfully*

**mysqli_multi_query($link, $update2);** - *Not Executed.*

Could anybody guide, if I might be missing something, or regarding the syntax.

Comment: Why not check for errors and see whether the queries work out at all? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: The query works if i am bundle them in one variable and execute just that.

Comment: `Not Executed` and `The query works` are quite contradictory statements

Comment: @YourCommonSense you have misinterpreted my question, kindly read again.

Comment: *sign* why not *simply look for what errors the query returns?* It's vastly more efficient than posting code on Stack Overflow and having lots of people guess what could be wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekMadhani you rather misinterpreted the comment you've got. The error message you will get is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Is `price` a `NUMERIC(4)` by any chance?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes it is

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, thanks have rectified that error, but still it won't insert. After capturing the error from mysql, it returned following message 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now', any idea what would that mean.

Comment: Change the type, it cannot hold your last value where all the statement fails... and for the sake of everything, use loop to build these 10 queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch all results - for example:

```
// here: first multi query

// fetch all results
while( mysqli_more_results($link) ){
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
}

// here: second multi query
```

Some SQL systems in some languages are **"lazy"**. They send query only when you ask for results (for example LINQ in C#). Maybe PHP do the same. It blocks connection waiting for your result fetching.

Comment: For "non-lazy" languages, I have read in the comments @ http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php that one line is adequate: while (mysqli_next_result($link)) {;} // flush multi_queries

Answer (score 1):

How about using just one query

```
UPDATE `temp` 
SET `price` = case when id = 1 then 1000 
                   when id = 2 then 2000
                   when id = 3 then 3000
                   when id = 4 then 4000
                   when id = 5 then 5000
                   when id = 6 then 6000
                   when id = 7 then 7000
                   when id = 8 then 8000
                   when id = 9 then 9000
                   when id = 10 then 10000
                   else price
              end
```

Comment: I would do that, but my above statement is in loop, hence on finish of every loop will execute that batch, and then work on next.

Comment: This answer provides the best suggested workaround for your error.  The truth is: best practice means performing a minimum number of database calls.  It doesn't matter how many how many loops you are running.  Build a single array of `id` and `price` values, then after all iterating is finished, build your single query and ship the data off to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE temp SET price = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stm = $link->prepare($sql);
$link->autocommit(FALSE);
$stm->bind_param("ii" $row['price'], $row['id']);
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $stm->execute();
}
$link->commit();
```

something like this but not tested. I always despised mysqli way of dealing with prepared statement

Answer (score -2):

Did you try combining all your updates into one and then running it?

```
 $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysqli_select_db($link, 'database_name');


 $update = " UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 1000 WHERE `id` = 1;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 2000 WHERE `id` = 2;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 3000 WHERE `id` = 3;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 4000 WHERE `id` = 4;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 5000 WHERE `id` = 5;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 6000 WHERE `id` = 6;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 7000 WHERE `id` = 7;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 8000 WHERE `id` = 8;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 9000 WHERE `id` = 9;
        UPDATE `temp` SET `price` = 10000 WHERE `id` = 10;";

  mysqli_multi_query($link, $update);
```

Comment: Tell me one reason how is that helpful?